# Why doesn't my embedded MongoDB regex work?

Tags: mongodb

When I query my database with:

```
{
    "metadata.text": "Hello world"
}
```

I get:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a455574d93b6a44cd95b210"
    },
    "metadata": {
        "text": "Hello world"
    }
}
```

I want to modify the query so that it matches anything with 'world'. When I try:

```
{
    "metadata.text": {
        "$regex": "/world/"
    }
}
```

I get no matches.

How do I modify my query so that it matches any text containing 'world'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
{
    "metadata.text": {
        "$regex": /world/
    }
}
```

**Or**

```
{
    "metadata.text": {
        "$regex": ".*world.*"
    }
}
```

---

If you know that your word is at the end then you can also do this:

```
{
    "metadata.text": {
        "$regex": /world$/
    }
}
```

**Or**

```
{
    "metadata.text": {
        "$regex": ".*world$"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to run the query through mlab.com and I get the following: 'We encountered an error while parsing your JSON. Please check your syntax (e.g. ensure you are using double quotes around both your field names and values) and try again'

Comment: @Mary I added both ways you can write it, check out the update